# How can I remap "`" in vim-latex?

Tags: vim, keyboard

I'm using vim-latex and I would like to use another key (tab, for example) instead of "`", since typing the latter is difficult here (shift + ´ + ´).

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, the documentation (http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-macros.html#Tex_Leader) says that I have to modify "g:Tex_Leader".

For example,

let g:Tex_Leader = ','

However, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To use `,` as the new prefix, in `$VIMFILES/ftplugin/tex/texrc` (create this file if it does not exist) add:

```
let g:Tex_Leader = ','
```

This does *not* seem to work when added to `$VIMFILES/ftplugin/tex.vim`.